# Restore Solr core into Solr Cloud collection - version 6.6.6

Tags: solr, lucene, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I am running Solr as stand alone mode and its version is 6.6.6. I have to shift this index to another Solr instance (same version) that is running in cloud mode. I have taken backup of core from old solr using replication API. For restoring on new Solr (cloud mode), I have got following exception:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException:java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/user/search/import-index/snapshot.abc-21-10-2020/backup.properties
```

Same configuration on Zookeeper is already deployed from old Solr to new one. What is the issue with this approach ? How to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar scenario with solr:8.5.2 and sadly is not possible to restore a core backup to a collection, but I did with following steps:

- core backup with replication handler:

```sh
curl 'HOST:8983/solr/CORE/replication?command=backup&name=backup-XXX&core=CORE&location=/tmp' -H 'Content-type:application/json'
```

- create collection with shard 1 (if you need more, you can use [split shard](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/shard-management.html) later)

```sh
solr create -c XXX [-d /your/configsets/if/any ] -shards 1
```

- stop solr
- delete everything but `core.properties`, `index` empty dir in SOLR_DATA/XXX_shard1_replica_nY, e.g.

```sh
cd /var/solr/data/XXX_shard1_replica_n1
rm -rf index/* snapshot_metadata  tlog
```

- copy core backup in SOLR_DATA/index/

```sh
cp snapshot.backup-XXX/* SOLR_DATA/index/
```

- start solr, you should have data restored